# quiero restringir acceso en pagina web

Tags: php, html

que hace este codigo de un htaccess

```html
<Files ~ "\.(htaccess|php)$">
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
</Files>
```

gracias amigos.

Comment: Bienvenido al sito .Angel. !!! te doy la bienvenida y te invito a que realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deniega el acceso a todos archivos htaccess y php que esten dentro del directorio que contenga ese htaccess. 
De todos modos no funcionará. La directiva `<files>` actúa sobre un solo archivo creo.

Lo correcto sería hacerlo con `<FilesMatch>`.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|php)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```